# Ruby 2.5 efficient way to delete ruby key if it contains a hash with only one key/val pair

Tags: ruby

Assuming a data structure that looks like the following:

```
foo = {
    'first': {
        'bar': 'foo'
    },
    'second': {
        'bar': 'foobar',
        'foo': 'barfoo'
    },
    'third': {
        'test': 'example'
    }
}
```

I want to remove all keys from the Hash `foo` that contain an entry that has only one key/val pair. In this particular case, after the operation is done, `foo` should only have left:

```
foo = {
    'second': {
        'bar': 'foobar',
        'foo': 'barfoo'
    }
}
```

as `foo['first']` and `foo['third']` only contain one key/val pair.

Comment: `foo.delete_if { |k, v| v.size == 1 }` would work.

Comment: @Stefan want to put the answer below so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Option 1 - `delete_if`

```
foo.delete_if { |_, inner| inner.one? }
```

- `delete_if` is destructive so it mutates the original hash
- This will let through empty hashes

#### Option 2 - `reject`

This doesn't mutate any more:

```
foo = foo.reject { |_, inner| inner.one? }
```

- This will let through empty hashes

#### Option 3 - `select`

No mutation plus different operator:

```
foo = foo.select { |_, inner| inner.size > 1 }
```

#### Option 4 - `many?` - Rails only

```
foo = foo.select { |_, inner| inner.many? }
```

- If you're using Rails it defines `#many?` for you which is any array with more than 1 item

#### Other Notes

- Used `_` for unused variables as that's a way of showing "this is irrelevant"
- Named the variable `inner` - convinced there's a better name but `value` could be confusing

Comment: What makes `inner.size == 1` a  _"negative condition"_?

Comment: Good question - I wasn't clear enough. That's not a negative condition. I meant a negative operator - I was referring to `delete_if`. :)

Comment: _"it's telling you what you **don't** want"_ – if you think of "keeping" as positive and "deleting" as negative then you're right. I think of it as `<action>_if` which to me is always positive – it decides which elements are chosen for `<action>`. It would be something else if the method was called `delete_unless`.

Comment: Since you included `many?` why not `reject {|_, v| v.one? }` which is part of ruby `Enumerable`

Comment: @Stefan - wow. That's a great point. I'd never thought of it like that. It's really not a negative operator at all. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a pair of option more, letting apart the way to check the condition.

Using **[Hash#keep_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if)**

```
foo.keep_if{ |_, v| v.size > 1 }
```

And a more complicated, **[Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)**:

```
foo.each_with_object({}){ |(k,v), h| h[k] = v if v.size > 1 }
```